# React select option list won't change when array changes

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have  `setOptions` that accepts a value, say an integer and uses that value as the first value of an array of size 7.

The problem is when another element calls `setOptions` with a new value, the option list does not change/update. `myOptions` does contain the new values since I can print them to the console.

What I'm expecting is for the select options values to change whenever `myOptions` changes.

```
import React from 'react';

class MyOption extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myOptions: []
    }
    this.setOptions = this.setOptions.bind(this);
  }

  setOptions(item) {
    let tempOpt = [];
    for(var i = item; i < 7; i++){
      var opt = "item " + i;
      this.state.tempOpt.push(<option key={i} value={opt}>{opt}</option>);
    }
    this.state.myOptions = tempOpt;
  }

  render() {
    this.setOptions(1);
    return(
      <div>
          <div>
              <select className="form-control" value={this.myValue}
                  onChange={(e) => this.setState({myValue: e.target.value})}>
                 {this.state.myOptions}
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>

    );

  }
}

export default MyOption;
```

Comment: I suggest you read the react docs before starting.

Answer (score 1):

You should manipulate `state` with `this.setState` method, which will trigger Component's re-render. Direct setting `state` property should be done in constructor only.

```
  setOptions(item) {
    let tempOpt = [];
    for(var i = item; i < 7; i++){
      var opt = "item " + i;
      tempOpt.push(<option key={i} value={opt}>{opt}</option>);
    }
    this.setState(() => ({ myOptions: tempOpt }))
  }
```

Second, you shouldn't call your setState function in the render function. Consider using `componentDidMount` method

Comment: So I added componentDidMount and inside of it added this.setOptions() but I get "Maximum update depth exceeded" error

Comment: It seems when setState is called, the renderer is call thus calling the setOptions(1)

Comment: @PLOW I've also changed this row: `this.state.tempOpt.push(<option key={i} value={opt}>{opt}</option>);` see it in my answer. Also, make sure to remove `this.setOptions(1);` from the render method. By this, setState should be only called on component mount and on select change handler